# I got the error session not created: No matching capabilities found by Selenium Edge WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I got the error session not created: No matching capabilities found by Selenium Edge WebDriver.
The weird thing Edge version is 89.0.774.50, also the same as Webdriver.
What causes it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Edge('/Users/mymac/Downloads/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver')
driver.get('mysite.com/signup')
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code and it worked! In MAC OS, you need to write like this.

```
desired_cap={}

driver = webdriver.Edge(('/Users/mymac/Downloads/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver', capabilities=desired_cap)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above-posted code, it looks like you have not added the `options.use_chromium = True` in your code. That might be causing this issue.

I suggest you refer to the example below and try to test it on your side.

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(executable_path = r"Edge_driver_path_here....\msedgedriver.exe", options = options) # Modify the path here...

driver.get("https://Website_URL_here...")
```

This sample code working fine with the MS Edge 89.* version.

I have tested this code on the Windows machine, if you are using a MAC machine then you can try to make the necessary changes in code to run it there.